# PHP Blog error "Unexpected End"

Tags: php, html

Hello i'm currently trying to create a blog for a school project and this is the code i've come up with.

```
<html>
<?php
$connection['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$connection['user'] = 'root';
$connection['password'] = 'ascent';
$connection['webdb'] = 'login';
$connection['newstable'] = 'news';

if (isset($_GET['newsid']))
{
    $id = (int)$_GET['newsid'];
    connect::selectDB('webdb');

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='".$id."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); ?>
    <div class='box_two_title'><?php echo $row['title']; ?></div>

    <?php 
    Some cool way to post the "body" row here.
    ?>
</html>
```

Basicly i just want it to post the news on the website, i've loaned a bit of code from here and there and there's a couple of errors whenever i try. Help is greatly appreciated. :-)

Comment: `<?php 
    Some cool way to post the "body" row here.
    ?>` do we need to answer that too?

Comment: Really cool, `<div>` without a `<head>` and `<body>`

Comment: @AlvinWong What's your point? `<head>` and `<body>` tags are optional, if you take a look into the spec. I would not recommend leaving it out for beginners, but it is perfectly valid ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen your code actually there are some errors in your code so firstly you have to connect with mysql database connection and then select DB. i am giving you the correct code so try this definitely it will help to create your blog.

```
<html>
<?php
$connection['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$connection['user'] = 'root';
$connection['password'] = 'ascent';
$connection['webdb'] = 'login';
$connection['newstable'] = 'news'; 
if (isset($_GET['newsid']))
{
//code to set database connection
$link = mysql_connect($connection['host'], $connection['user'], $connection['password']);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
// make login the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($connection['webdb'], $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}
//get news id
$id = (int)$_GET['newsid'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='".$id."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); ?>
<div class='box_two_title'><?php echo $row['title']; ?></div>
<?php //    Some cool way to post the "body" row here. } ?> </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the closing curly bracket, add `<? } ?>` before the closing `<html>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is basically complaining, because you didn't close the curly brackets `{` of your if clause.

```
<html>
<?php
$connection['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$connection['user'] = 'root';
$connection['password'] = 'ascent';
$connection['webdb'] = 'login';
$connection['newstable'] = 'news';

if (isset($_GET['newsid']))
{
    $id = (int)$_GET['newsid'];
    connect::selectDB('webdb');

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='".$id."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); ?>
    <div class='box_two_title'><?php echo $row['title']; ?></div>

    <?php 
//    Some cool way to post the "body" row here.
}
    ?>
</html>
```

Besides, although you're just starting with PHP, you should use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) to access the database. the `mysql_X` functions are deprecated.

When at least while developing check the error, MySQL might be returning to see why to query failed.

Comment: Thanks but now it's not posting anything at all??

Comment: @user1644279 You added a `?newsid=123` with a valid id to the query? If so, check for MySQL errors at least by using `mysql_error()`.